# Android toast won't appear

Tags: android, toast

It's getting really annoying. I'm trying to show a simple toast and it will just not appear.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements UserPromptDialogListener  {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static String SELECTION_TYPE="type";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CharSequence text = "I am a toast sss";
        Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t1.show();

        Log.d("AAA", "After toast show");
    }
    //other methods
}
```

I have tried `this`, `MainActivity.this`, etc. but it does not seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I think on create is wrong try it in one of the other lifecycle prozedures.

Comment: Thanks JackTools. But why do you think on create is wrong ? I tried onStart. But toast does not appear. Toast does not appear anywhere in my application. So I thought, I will start with the simplest which is onCreate of main activity. But that too does not work.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on but another note is that you don't need to "getApplicationContext". Using "this" should be fine.

Comment: @Margi What are you testing this on? And having a `Toast` in `onCreate` is fine, and works.

Comment: Hi Steven , I am testing on my Samsung S3 device

Answer (score 2):

I just tested and this code and works fine in `onCreate`, I see the `Toast` right as the `Activity` is created.

One way to trigger `onCreate`:

1. Close your app completely by pressing back until you reach the home screen.
2. Reopen your app using the launcher icon or recent apps (press recent button on 4.0+ or hold home button).
3. Check to see if there is a `Toast`.

Another way to trigger `onCreate`:

1. Rotate the device, the `Activity` will be destroyed and recreated.

This will ensure your `Activity` goes through `onCreate` and you see the `Toast`. Tell me if either of those are working for you (they are for me).

Comment: Thanks Steven , I did what you suggested. But still no luck !

Comment: Test this on an emulator, maybe this is something funky Samsung is doing with the S3 (this is why I hate fragmentation ;))

Comment: Just a FYI. The toast would appear on my device two days back. Since then I have added a lot of funtionalities and integrated with Facebook SDK as well. So, after doing all these, the toast does not appear anywhere in the application.

Comment: Yes Steven.I just changed the code a little bit to show toast on click of a button. So, I could see the toast on emulator but not on device.So its a device specific issue ? If yes then why was I able to see the toast on device two days back and not now?

Comment: @Margi it could be device specific. I've seen issues on S3's where they call lifecycle events in different orders... welcome to Android development. Another thing, if you are only showing some of your code, it's hard for us to diagnose what is really going on. What you have **posted** should work fine, assuming you don't have other code affecting it. However, try your `Toast` using `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`, see if that does anything.

Comment: Hey, after googling for a while, I found out the problem. In my app setting , I had to check 'Show Notifications' and now I am able to see the toast in my device. (Face palm...almost 6 hrs wasted )

Comment: @Margi please share what you found, it may help anyone else who runs into this.

Comment: In other words, if you disable application notifications, Toasts also are disabled for that particular application.There's a bug filed on Android bug database;

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and it works fine for me,there is nothing wrong with using Toast's `makeText()` method in `onCreate()` method.One way of troubleshooting would be to create a button and on its `onClick()` method,try to show the Toast.In this way you shall be able to know whether the problem is with the Toast or the activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you still facing the same problem, try to uninstall Google App Update by Settings > Apps > Google App > Uninstall Update

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Android Emulator bug for me. Simply restarting it fixed the problem!