# Toast message not getting displayed on selecting context menu item in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Toast message not getting displayed on selecting context menu item in Android Studio

Here is the main activity I used
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.endsempracmad;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Home Activity");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Javatpoint",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    // Set up the action bar to display the overflow menu button
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}

 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)        
 {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // Show the context menu
        registerForContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        openContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        unregisterForContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id== R.id.context_item_1){

            return true;}

    if (id== R.id.context_item_2){
    return true;}

        else{
       
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);}


    }
}
```

this is the context menu i used
Here, we register the content view (i.e., the root view of the activity's layout) for the context menu, then open the context menu by calling openContextMenu with the content view as the argument. Finally, we unregister the content view from the context menu to ensure that it doesn't interfere with other menus in the future.
Defined context menu items in a menu resource file res/menu folder:
context_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/context_item_1"
      android:title="Context Item 1" />
   <item android:id="@+id/context_item_2"
    android:title="Context Item 2" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have missed to add the Toast message inside the conditions of context menu item.

For more clarification you can make it like below

```
            override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            val id = item.itemId
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                // Show the context menu
                registerForContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                openContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                unregisterForContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                return true
            }

           if (id== R.id.context_item_1){
               // you should add Toast to be show when click on first item
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hello Javatpoint - first item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                return true;
           }

            if (id== R.id.context_item_2){
                // you should add Toast to be show when click on second item
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hello Javatpoint - second item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                return true;}

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
```

Another note if Toast in the `onCreate()` method is not working make sure to try it using physical device as emulator sometimes is not working good with Toast as per the below link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241566/android-toast-wont-appear]